# PS Script error when trying to remove old search topology SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, topology

```
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $OldTopologyId -SearchApplication $ServiceApplication
```

Getting the below error when running the above PSScript

> Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "c93430a5-8106-4b44-93ff-3bfe0582a381" value 
>   of type "System.Guid" to type "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.SearchTopologyPipeBind".
>   At C:\install\Start-2013SearchServices.ps1:225 char:57
>   +             Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $OldTopologyId -SearchAp ...
>   +                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.RemoveSearchTopology

Answer (score 2):

Use [Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spenterprisesearchtopology?view=sharepoint-ps) and then pass that into the Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology

```
$topo = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ServiceApplication -Identity 'c93430a5-8106-4b44-93ff-3bfe0582a381'
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology $topo
```